# How can I specify a default value for a field in a JDO entity on appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I recently added Text field to one of my Entities that cannot be null.  I'd like to set a default value for it, so that all of the Entities that I stored before I added the field will be populated with an empty string.  Is this possible with JDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though not as trivially as you were probably expecting.

**Limitations**

1. Will [time out if it
   takes more then 30 seconds](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer),
   unless you run it as a task, in which
   case it will [time out if it takes
   more then 10 minutes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Execution).
2. There's no smarter way to get only
   the entities that need updated since
   you [can't query on a property that
   doesn't exist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries).

**Workarounds**

1. You'll want to look into the
   [appengine-mapreduce project](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to
   get an implementation  that can
   complete with more then 10 minutes
   wall-clock time.
2. None known.

**Code**

```
void updateNullBarField() {
  final Text DEFAULT_BAR = new Text("bar");

  PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper
    .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
  PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
  Query query = pm.newQuery(Foo.class);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Collection<Foo> foos = pm.detachCopyAll((List<Foo>) query.execute());

  for (Foo foo : foos) {
    if (foo.bar == null) {
      foo.bar = DEFAULT_BAR;
      pm.detachCopy(pm.makePersistent(foo));
    }
  }
}
```